# Write json in the file from list of json

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am calling one API several times to get the result. The result is returned in json format. I am saving all the results in a list. Once all the data is received then I write the content of the list to a file using the following code. My end goal is to save the results in a file with valid json. However the following code adds `'\'` to the json result in file. Can someone please help me solve the issue.

```
result = []
// In a for loop I append json results to this list. I have not written the code here.
// Then I use this code to write to a file.
with open(host_log_path, 'w') as log_file:
    log_file.write(json.dumps(result))
```

sample current output with slashes:

```
["{\"hdr\":{\"msgt\":\"InitialState\",\"ver\":\"CV-NOTSET\",\"uid\":1,\"seq\":1}}"]
```

Comment: This means that `result` is already JSON, you don't need to call `json.dumps()`.

Comment: Actually, it appears to be a list containing a JSON string.

Comment: The list contains multiple records with json string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you're getting indicates that `result` contains a list of JSON strings, not a list of objects. You don't need to call `json.dumps()`, they're already formatted as JSON. You should just write each of them as a separate line in the log file.

```
with open(host_log_path, "a") as log_file:
    for msg in result:
        log_file.write((msg if type(msg) is str else json.dumps(msg)) + "\n")
```

You also should use `a` mode to append to the log file. Your code clears out the old contents each time yuo open it.

If you want to write them as a single JSON array, you can call `json.loads()` in the loop.

```
with open(host_log_path, "w") as log_file:
    msgs = [json.loads(msg) if type(msg) is str else msg for msg in result]
    json.dump(msgs, log_file)
```

Comment: This solves the problem of slashe but how can i make all the items part of the same object something like in an array kind of thing. [ ]

Comment: If you want to do that you need to use `json.loads()` to parse the JSON, collect them all in a list, then dump that.

Comment: Can you give a code example because when I already tried json.loads() but it didn`t worked. May be i missed something very simple.

Comment: I added that to the answer.

Comment: json.lods() lines gives me this error.  return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Are all the results like you showed in the question?

Comment: Some items in the result list is an actual json array

Comment: I've added a conditionals to the code. If the item is a string it treats it as JSON, otherwise it's an object that needs to be dumped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192742/discussion-between-hussain-ali-and-barmar).